# many to many and one to one association on the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I can get this to work in the rails console just can figure out how to implement the code.

Using a HABTM association a User can be on many Teams and a Team can have many Users.
but a Team is owned by one User and a User can only own one Team.

how can it be done so that when the team is created(which works), I can associated the one to one relationship also?

I'm having trouble with the code in the set_user_on_team method.It currently produces 2 team records with the second having all the correct association and the first just has the user as a member of the team.

```
1.9.3p194 :005 > Team.all
Team Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" 
=> [#<Team id: 1, name: "username", dept_no: nil, created_at: "2012-07-27 12:19:00", updated_at: "2012-07-27 12:19:00", user_id: nil>, #<Team id: 2, name: "username", dept_no: nil, created_at: "2012-07-27 12:19:00", updated_at: "2012-07-27 12:19:00", user_id: 1>] 
1.9.3p194 :006 > user.teams
Team Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" INNER JOIN "teams_users" ON "teams"."id" = "teams_users"."team_id" WHERE "teams_users"."user_id" = 1
=> [#<Team id: 1, name: "username", dept_no: nil, created_at: "2012-07-27 12:19:00", updated_at: "2012-07-27 12:19:00", user_id: nil>, #<Team id: 2, name: "username", dept_no: nil, created_at: "2012-07-27 12:19:00", updated_at: "2012-07-27 12:19:00", user_id: 1>] 
1.9.3p194 :007 > user.team
=> #<Team id: 2, name: "username", dept_no: nil, created_at: "2012-07-27 12:19:00", updated_at: "2012-07-27 12:19:00", user_id: 1>
```

1.9.3p194 :008 >

I have be able to achive this in the rails console like this:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > user = User.first
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 1, email: "test@example.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$MiVSB4RuFL5ubagq7YLgA.NEk9AY.uHBz.i6pfebRJgC...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2012-07-27 11:26:11", last_sign_in_at: "2012-07-27 11:26:11", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2012-07-27 11:26:11", updated_at: "2012-07-27 11:26:11"> 
1.9.3p194 :002 > user.teams
Team Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" INNER JOIN "teams_users" ON "teams"."id" = "teams_users"."team_id" WHERE "teams_users"."user_id" = 1
=> [#<Team id: 1, name: "username", dept_no: nil, created_at: "2012-07-27 11:26:11", updated_at: "2012-07-27 11:26:11", user_id: nil>, #<Team id: 2, name: "username", dept_no: nil, created_at: "2012-07-27 11:26:11", updated_at: "2012-07-27 11:26:11", user_id: nil>] 
1.9.3p194 :003 > user.team
Team Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
=> nil 
1.9.3p194 :004 > team = User.first.teams.first
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
Team Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" INNER JOIN "teams_users" ON "teams"."id" = "teams_users"."team_id" WHERE "teams_users"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
=> #<Team id: 1, name: "username", dept_no: nil, created_at: "2012-07-27 11:26:11", updated_at: "2012-07-27 11:26:11", user_id: nil> 
1.9.3p194 :005 > user.team = team
(0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
(0.4ms)  UPDATE "teams" SET "user_id" = 1, "updated_at" = '2012-07-27 11:27:41.948931' WHERE "teams"."id" = 1
(0.0ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> #<Team id: 1, name: "username", dept_no: nil, created_at: "2012-07-27 11:26:11", updated_at: "2012-07-27 11:27:41", user_id: 1> 
1.9.3p194 :006 > team.user
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 1, email: "test@example.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$MiVSB4RuFL5ubagq7YLgA.NEk9AY.uHBz.i6pfebRJgC...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2012-07-27 11:26:11", last_sign_in_at: "2012-07-27 11:26:11", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2012-07-27 11:26:11", updated_at: "2012-07-27 11:26:11"> 
1.9.3p194 :007 >
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base


  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
  has_one :team

  after_save :set_user_on_team

  private

    def set_user_on_team
      users_team = teams.create(:name => 'username' ) 
      self.team = users_team
   end
end
```

I tried the following code and it also produces to team records

```
def set_user_on_team
      self.team = teams.create(:name => 'username' ) 
end
```

Team.rb

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :user

end
```

Comment: Can you show the error that it's generating?

Answer (score 0):

Being on a team and owning a team are two different relationships, so give them different names and you'll be fine:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
  has_one :owned_team, :class_name => "Team"
end
```

Comment: I can see your logic, but is shouldn't be required to achieve this. I have updated my question to show a working example in the rails console

Comment: You're right that it isn't necessary, but it both increases readability and can also prevent some errors like using `team` as a local variable, but really referring to `self.team`

Comment: self.team has almost got me there, but now its creating 2 team records. I have updated the question with new code and explaination

Comment: try switching the after_save to an after_create so that it only happens once. Adding some types of associations will cause the record itself to be saved, according to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: after_crate gets rid of the double record, but is still producing some strange behaviour user.owned_team returns the owned team but team.owner returned nil